# How to run JSR223 PreProcessor only once

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan in jMeter that requires some parameters that needs to be calculated before running the test. In order to calculate these parameters, I created a JSR223 PreProcessor directly under test plan as seen below.

[image: Test Plan]

My problem is PreProcessor  seems to run before every request which is not what I want. I need to calculate these parameters only once and use them in testing.

Is there a way to run the JSR223 PreProcessor only once, or should I use another method?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

As @ubik-load-pack suggested, I tried "setUp Thread Group" as following but variables created in the code was not available under "Thread Group". They were also present neither in the logs (logging is used in the code) nor in the View Results Tree (via Debug PostProcessor)

[image]

I also tried "Once Only Controller" which also didn't work, same as above.

[image]

For more information here is content of my JSR223 PreProcessor. (Not the whole code, there will be more variables here so using date functions is not a solution for me by the way.)

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By design a PreProcessor runs before any Sampler runs.

So if you want to run something only once per user, you can do the following:

- Use a [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) and put in it a JSR223 Sampler that will contain your code.

If you want **to do it once for all users**, then use a [setupThreadGroup](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)
 that will contain your JSR223 Sampler and configure it with 1 thread. It will run once before the regular Thread Groups are started.

**EDIT after you updated your question:**

- As I wrote, you cannot use the setupThreadGroup approach if you want to reuse variables in Thread Groups so stick to OnceOnlyController approach for your request
- With the Once Only Controller it is not working because you misread my answer, I am suggesting to use a JSR223 **Sampler** not PreProcessor as a preprocessor will run only if there is a sampler that runs.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use "setUp Thread Group" and put a PreProcessor inside it but it doesn't seem to work. I can't see it in results tree also jMeter variables created in the preprocessor is not available in Main Thread Group. Should I change any other settings?

Comment: From you comment, what you want is to have variables per user, so use the Once Only Controller solution I gave

Comment: Actually I am trying to use the same parameters for every user so "setUp Thread Group" was the ideal solution. I also tried "Once Only Controller" which also didn't work. I will update my question in order to provide more information.

Comment: You cannot use setupThreadGroup for your case as threads started in setupThread Group will be killed once finished and new ones started for Thread Group. So you approach should be based on Once Only Controller

Comment: You are right, I misread your answer. With OnceOnlyController it works like a charm. Thanks for your passion : )

Comment: I want to run the preprocessor only once at a time for multiple samplers. I want to pass the initial values to multiple samplers. could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Sampler, and you have multiple ThreadGroups, then you'll have to copy that sampler into each ThreadGroup, since you can't put Samplers outside of ThreadGroups.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jsr223 PreProcessor with:

```
if(vars.get("init")=="OK") return;
vars.put("init","OK")

//your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a slightly dirty workaround at the top of the preprocessor:

```
log.info("in PreProcessor. Sampler name: " + sampler.getName())
if (sampler.getName() != "HTTP Request") {
    log.info("not running again")
    return
}
```

In my case I cannot add another sampler because it will mess up my timer calculations.